# Ruby/Shoes cannot get numeric value from selection of list_box

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, shoes

I'm trying to get an integer from a conditional statement based on the selection on `list_box`. Just cannot make it work. Also, I would like to be able to remove `@acuity = para`. My code is based on this: [list_box won't use default value on startup - Shoes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069073/list-box-wont-use-default-value-on-startup-shoes)

```
Shoes.app :title=> 'Procedural', :width => 300, :height => 200 do 

@list_box = list_box :items => ["1- Ad lib", "2- Assist of SB", "3- Assist of 1", "4- Assist of 2"]                        

   button 'Compute' do
        @acuity.text = @list_box.text
  if @acuity == "1- Ad lib"
        @mobility = 11
  elsif @acuity == "2- Assist of SB"
        @mobility = 22
  elsif @acuity == "3- Assist of 1"
    @mobility = 33
  elsif @acuity == "4- Assist of 2"
    @mobility = 44
  end

      end

    @acuity = para

    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what your goal is. To display @mobility somewhere?  Just assigning a value to the @mobility variable does nothing.

```
Shoes.app do

  @choice_map = {
    "1- Ad lib"       => 11,
    "2- Assist of SB" => 22,
    "3- Assist of 1"  => 33,
    "4- Assist of 2"  => 44
  }

  para "Choose item:"
  @my_listbox = list_box(:items => @choice_map.keys) 

  button 'Compute' do
    @mobility = @choice_map[@my_listbox.text]
  end

end
```

To prove that @mobility contains the correct value, you need to display the value somewhere:

```
Shoes.app do

  @choice_map = {
    "1- Ad lib"       => 11,
    "2- Assist of SB" => 22,
    "3- Assist of 1"  => 33,
    "4- Assist of 2"  => 44
  }

  @my_listbox = list_box(items: @choice_map.keys)

  @my_para = para 'show computed results here'

  button 'Compute' do
    @mobility = @choice_map[@my_listbox.text]
    @my_para.text = @mobility
  end

end
```

Your code actually works fine with a minor change:

```
Shoes.app :title => 'Procedural', :width => 300, :height => 200 do 

@list_box = list_box :items => ["1- Ad lib", "2- Assist of SB", "3- Assist of 1", "4- Assist of 2"]                        

@my_para = para 'show computed results here'

button 'Compute' do
  @acuity = @list_box.text   #<---CHANGE HERE

  if @acuity == "1- Ad lib"
    @mobility = 11
  elsif @acuity == "2- Assist of SB"
    @mobility = 22
  elsif @acuity == "3- Assist of 1"
    @mobility = 33
  elsif @acuity == "4- Assist of 2"
    @mobility = 44
  end

  @my_para.text = @mobility

end
```

If you don't need the button:

```
Shoes.app do

  @choice_map = {
    "1- Ad lib"       => 11,
    "2- Assist of SB" => 22,
    "3- Assist of 1"  => 33,
    "4- Assist of 2"  => 44
  }

  para "Choose item:"

  @default = "2- Assist of SB"
  @mobility = @choice_map[@default]

  @my_listbox = list_box(items: @choice_map.keys, choose: @default) do |list|
    @mobility = @choice_map[list.text]
  end

end
```

The block given to list_box() is only executed onchange, so you have to set an initial value for @mobility.

You would think something like the following would be able to retrieve the initial value in the listbox:

```
Shoes.app do

  @choice_map = {
    "1- Ad lib"       => 11,
    "2- Assist of SB" => 22,
    "3- Assist of 1"  => 33,
    "4- Assist of 2"  => 44
  }

  para "Choose item:"

  @my_listbox = list_box(items: @choice_map.keys) do |list|
    @mobility = @choice_map[list.text]
    @my_para.text = @mobility
  end

  @mobility = @choice_map[@my_listbox.text]
  @my_para = para @mobility 
end
```

But apparently the listbox does not exist until after the app block finishes executing, so you can't retrieve @my_listbox.text inside the app block.

Comment: Thanks very much, your solutions were extremely easy to follow. To explain myself more clearly, @mobility will be added to several other variables, I was just having trouble with that part. Many thanks!!

Comment: Hey, there's one potential problem with my code: you can't rely on the order of the keys in a hash in ruby < 1.9. With the choices you provided in your example, you could just sort `@choice_map.keys`, i.e. `@choice_map.keys.sort`, but in general you would need to create an array of the keys in the order you want them to appear in the listbox, so @choice_map isn't quite as convenient in ruby 1.8.